# Django settings not set

Tags: python, django, django-settings, django-pipeline

I'm having trouble with [django-pipeline](http://django-pipeline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/compilers.html) which requires you to set the

`settings.STYLUS_BINARY` for the stylus compiler.

In my settings.py I have the following:

`STYLUS_BINARY = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'stylus')`

If I print this to the console I see the folder:

`c:/Users/chowza/myproject/node_modules/.bin/stylus`

However, if I dig into the django-pipeline module that actually uses `settings.STYLUS_BINARY` and add a print there I see the following when printing `settings.STYLUS_BINARY`:

`('usr/bin/env/','stylus')`

That is what the default path of `STYLUS_BINARY` is set to according to `django-pipeline`

At the top of this module is a function that says `from pipeline.conf import settings` so I assume my settings file is being imported.

That tells me that my `settings.STYLUS_BINARY` is not set.

I am using `python manage.py collectstatic --settings myproject.settings` so that I can compile stylus files to css with `settings.STYLUS_BINARY`.

So my question is why is the settings variable not set? what am I doing wrong?

Note: this was tested on Windows and on Heroku deployment

Comment: Do you get any error logs ?

Comment: @Jclarke the error is a non descript error saying a file is missing when running django-pipeline's stylus_compiler, hence I went to print the location of the `settings.STYLUS_BINARY` in the stylus_compiler and found it say `/user/bin/env/` instead of `c:/users/chowza/myproject/node_modules/.bin/stylus` which is what I would expect given that I wrote that in my settings file

Comment: Hey i just tested it got the same error. I updated my compressors and the error went away and all the files that weren't collected were collected.

Comment: @Jclarke what do you mean updated your compressors? My compressors are npm installed as of last week. I can't imagine them out of date.

Comment: I meant in the settings. I'd ignore it though.

Answer (score 0):

Spent a couple days on this. Wasted a lot of time.

Libraries that have bad documentation suck.

in settings.py

`STYLUS_BINARY = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'node_modules', '.bin', 'stylus')`

should be:

`PIPELINE['STYLUS_BINARY'] = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'node_modules', '.bin','stylus'),`

This is assuming you have a `node_modules/.bin/stylus`. The important thing is that it is not set as a constant but as a hash of PIPELINE.